# Why does Stack Overflow suggest a completely illogical tag?

Tags: support

I'm just wondering why Stack Overflow suggested this entirely illogical tag.

[image: tag suggestions example that includes C++]

Since I have already put "Java" as one of my tags, why is it suggesting that my code can be two languages at once?

The problem with suggestions like that is that if I am on a site I don't know well (like Mathematics) I often presume the suggested tags are correct, and will often add them in without any actual knowledge of the tag.

Just imagine if someone didn't know what a "C++" was, and added the tag? They'd probably get downvoted out of existence, or at least have to have someone editing the tags.

The point is, suggested tags are fine for experienced users but for new users who don't know much, then incorrect suggested tags can be extremely confusing.

Comment: It is a machine, it doesn't care much about the sensibilities of a Java programmer.  The top related tag by a factor 4 for [opengl] is the [c++] tag.

Comment: "Just imagine if someone didn't know what a "C++" was, and added the tag?" Why would anyone add a tag if they don't know what's about? That makes absolutely no sense at all, and if someone actually does that then they deserve all the downvotes they get.

Answer (score 7):

> Just imagine if someone didn't know what a "C++" was, and added the tag? They'd probably get downvoted out of existence, or at least have to have someone editing the tags.

Why would you add tags you don't understand is beyond me.

> But for new users who don't know much, then incorrect suggested tags can be extremely confusing.

Again, the same problem with that. They are suggestions. You aren't forced to put those tags. Use your better judgement.

Comment: This. No feature, however sophisticated, can replace common sense.

Comment: @Yannis People don't have common sense. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: "lwjgl" is a random string rolled by computer script :D This user should be banned from creating new tags for sure.

Comment: @ErezZrihen Are you sure you didn't mean LightWeight Java Game Library? ;)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I didn't know that "lwjgl" stands for **L**ight**W**eight **J**ava **G**ame **L**ibrary. This is not good to create tags so shortly.